# Vue Test Utils & Vue 3: How to effectively test onKeyStroke() event

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3

I'm currently utilising `vueuse/core`'s `onKeyStroke` event sensor.

```js
onKeyStroke(
      'c',
      (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        showAsterisms.value = false
        showConstellations.value = !showConstellations.value
      },
      {
        target: document
      }
    )
```

I'm looking to test this functionality with the following:

```js
it('Constellations Should Be Visible', async () => {
    wrapper.trigger('keydown', {
      key: 'c'
    })

    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()

    const canvas = wrapper.find('canvas')

    const canvasAttributes = canvas.attributes()

    expect(canvasAttributes['data-constellations']).toBe('true')
  })
```

Where the wrapper is a mounted component:

```js
const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
  props: {
    ...
  }
})
```

I then have the following bound property on the canvas:

```html
<canvas :data-constellations="showConstellations" />
```

However, with this setup, it seems that this particular setup the data-constellations attribute on the canvas elmenent is always set to the default false, and after the keyPress it is not updated ...

Could someone advise me please on what I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onKeyStroke` attaches the event listener to the document (via the `{ target: document }` option), so the test has to [dispatch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) the `keydown` event on the document:

```js
it('Constellations Should Be Visible', async () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent)

  // simulate keypress on document
  const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'c' })
  document.dispatchEvent(event)

  await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
  const canvas = wrapper.find('canvas')
  const canvasAttributes = canvas.attributes()
  expect(canvasAttributes['data-constellations']).toBe('true')
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-testing-vueuse-onkeystroke?file=tests/unit/MyComponent.spec.js)

Comment: Ahhhhh I see. Yes, I was thinking if the `trigger()` was attaching to the right node. I guess in this sense we need to `await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()` as well, because we can't use `await wrapper.trigger()`. Thank you for this!